# How do I execute a block of code multiple times?

Tags: plotting, graphics, random

Rudimentary pseudoconceptial question:

I have a specific block of code that uses random variables and generates a plot at the end based on random code. I want my code to run 10 different times to get 10 different results. Essentially, I would like to execute this code like 10 times and generate 10 different plots. How would I modify the syntax using this?

Edit: It's giving me the same plot 10 times, which I don't want, am I doing something wrong?

[image: It's giving me the same plot 10 times, which I don't want]

Comment: Consider `Table[]` or `Do[]`.

Comment: Or `(YourCode) & /@ Range[10];`:D

Comment: @belisarius Oh, that's clever! Quick & dirty, gets the job done, I like it!

Comment: John, could you add just the code you used to your question, as TEXT, instead of the screenshot? I can't read well enough off of your screenshot.

Comment: @MarcoB http://i.stack.imgur.com/goXLq.png :P

Comment: John, what is the definition of Xt[] in your code? That's what you are using to generate the data that you then plot. More in general, you are **repeating the plotting operation, but not the data generation operation**. In other words, you keep plotting the same `g1` data set over and over; of course it's going to give you the same plot every time! :-) You need to include the data generation step in the block of code that is repeated.

Comment: @belisarius Thank you, but I'll admit that I was hoping OP would save me the retyping :-)

Comment: I am closing this as **too broad**; to me this is in a way asking for an overview of the entire programming architecture of *Mathematica* as running a block of code is a fundamental operation; with knowledge of the language this can probably be done one hundred different ways, and if one cannot think of a way he likely has little knowledge of the language.  This does not mean that the question cannot be revised into something more focused.

Comment: @MarcoB I know, I know :P

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was writing down the 99nth way when you closed the question :D

Comment: @belisarius http://i.imgur.com/0mVshjB.jpg -- as always if you have a unique answer of general interest I will reopen a question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I can't remember. I've deleted the notebook so no point in reopening. All good.

Answer (score 5):

**You can do this in *very many* ways.**

Probably one of the simplest conceptually could be to **wrap your repeating code in a `Table`** with a constant iterator:

```
Table[
 Module[
  {data},
  data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]],
     100];
  Histogram[data]
  ],
 {6}
]
```

[image: Many random plots]

Alternatively, you could use **control structures** instructions such as `While`, `For`, `Do`... You can find more information on the guide on [Loops and Control Structures](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LoopsAndControlStructures.html) in the documentation.

It may be worthwhile to demonstrate the usage of `Do`. `Do` does NOT return any output from inside its body. Therefore you need a way of collecting the output as it is generated (take a look at this tutorial on [*Collecting Expressions during Evaluation*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html). [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) are a very efficient way to do that.

For instance, you could reproduce what we did above as follows:

```
Reap[
  Do[
   Module[
    {data},
    data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], 100];
    Sow[ Histogram[data] ]
   ],
   {6}
  ]
] [[2]]
```

The result is a list of lists of the expressions generated by the repeated evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

I post this answer just as exploiting some other functions.
Barring transcriptional, interpretational and indexing errors:

```
func[s0_, m_, s_, t_, h_] := Module[{d = Sqrt[h], n = t/h, rv, x},
  rv = {0}~Join~RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, d], n];
  x = Accumulate[rv];
  MapIndexed[{(#2[[1]] - 1) h, 
     s0 Exp[(m - s^2/2) (#2[[1]] - 1) h + s #1]} &, x]
  ]
sim[s0_, m_, s_, t_, h_, num_] := 
 Table[ListPlot[func[s0, m, s, t, h], Joined -> True], {num}]
```

Simulating nine walks (just to make grid):

```
Grid[Partition[sim[33.78, -0.124, 0.2725, 0.5, 0.001, 9], 3], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]